# Populating a database table with returned JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm looking to store some JSON content from a Drupal website to a database table in a PhoneGap app. I am using ajax to do this. When I run the following code and check the table, I am told that it is empty. Does anybody know how I could populate this table?

```
$('#newDiv').live('pageshow',function(){

    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM 'tableA'", [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        alert("Table: " + len + " rows were found.");
        }
    }

    function createTable(tx) {

        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "tableA"');
        var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'tableA' (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, step VARCHAR(50), text VARCHAR(50))";
        tx.executeSql(sql, [], successCB, errorCB); 
    }

    db.transaction(createTable, errorCB, successCB);

   $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        type: 'post',
        data: 'tid=4',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('new_page_node_view - failed to retrieve page node');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
        },     
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (node_index,node_value) {
               db.transaction(function(tx){
                       tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'tableA' (step, text) VALUES (?, ?)",[node_value.title, node_value.body]);
               });
            });
          }
      });

    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB, successCB);


});
```

Comment: You're running the `queryDB` transaction before waiting for the AJAX to complete. You should do it in the `success` callback.

Comment: @Barmar This is certainly one problem with this.  Another issue is that not all the inserts could be completed when he calls the queryDB - I made an edit to the script that will call queryDB at the appropriate time after all the inserts have fully completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey tipssch try this -

```
  var numInserts = 0;

  $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        type: 'post',
        data: 'tid=4',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('new_page_node_view - failed to retrieve page node');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
        },     
        success: function (data) {
            numInserts = data.length; // num of inserts to expect (assumes data is in array of objects)

            $.each(data, function (node_index,node_value) {
               db.transaction(function(tx){
                       tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'tableA' (step, text) VALUES (?, ?)",[node_value.title, node_value.body],
                       function(tx, results){
                            numInserts--; // decrement 1 from expected num of inserts
                            if (numInserts == 0){
                                db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB, successCB);
                            }
                       }, 
                       function(tx, err){
                        console.log("insert error");
                        if (err){
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                       });
               });
            });
        }
  });
```

/Update - Answering why the above approach is necessary.

Ok, so you might wonder why you don't just call `queryDB` right away in the success callback of the AJAX call after your $.each loop, like this below -

```
   $.ajax({
        url: myURL,
        type: 'post',
        data: 'tid=4',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('new_page_node_view - failed to retrieve page node');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
        },     
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (node_index,node_value) {
               db.transaction(function(tx){
                    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'tableA' (step, text) VALUES (?, ?)",[node_value.title, node_value.body]);
               });
            });
            db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB, successCB); // <-- the inserts could not all be finished when this gets called
        }
   });
```

Let's say you have 1000 records you are going to insert from your JSON result.  These inserts will not be finished when you call `db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB, successCB);` in the success of the AJAX call.  You must implement a success callback to your `tx.executeSql` insert to know when an insert has finished.

What I did instead in my first approach above will allow for all the inserts to be fully completed before you call the `queryDB` function.  I added an inline success and fail callback to the `tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'tableA' (step, text) VALUES (?, ?)",[node_value.title, node_value.body]);`.  I always suggest doing this for any of your WebSQL in PhoneGap (they don't have to be inline either).

I did extensive WebSQL transactions in PhoneGap during my previous job.  Much of this involved looping through JSON and writing it into local database tables.  The real difficult issue occurs when you have many inserts and trying to figure out when they are all completely done before notifying the user or in your case pulling the data out that was just written.

So... the trick you will learn to do in the case of inserting is -

> 1. Count the number of inserts your are expecting to perform and store it in a variable.
> 2. In the success callback of your `tx.executeSql` insert subtract 1 from your variable that holds the number of inserts you are expecting.
> 3. Once the variable gets to 0 in the `tx.executeSql` success callback then you know all of your inserts have finished.

Simple example with 1 insert -

```
// wrong approach here
db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'tableA' (step, text) VALUES (?, ?)",["foo", "bar"]);
    // it will start the select query before the insert has completed
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM 'tableA'", [], querySuccess, errorCB);
});

// the right approach here
db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO 'tableA' (step, text) VALUES (?, ?)",["foo", "bar"], insertDone, insertFail);
});

function insertDone(tx, results){
    // insert is done, now you can run the queryDB
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM 'tableA'", [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function insertFail(tx, err){
    console.log("insert error");
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps clarify why I used the first approach instead of just running the `queryDB` in the success callback of the AJAX call.

Hopefully all this will help someone in the future, lol.

Comment: That worked, thanks a million Ross. Would you mind explaining why my own code wasn't giving me anything?

Comment: @tipssch Barmar was correct above about indicating that you were calling the `queryDB` transaction before waiting for the AJAX to complete.  However, even if you called `queryDB` in the `success` callback of your AJAX call your inserts will likely not have completed yet.  The gotcha here is that when you use WebSQL in PhoneGap it is asynchronous.  I always recommend implementing a callback inside your `tx.executeSql` that will trigger whenever the transaction has completed (the callback doesn't have to be inline either).  I'm going edit my answer and illustrate more.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was extremely helpful! I really appreciate it